# Solr Multivalued Field Detecting Language

Tags: indexing, solr

"I want to ask, simplifying a sample. I have 2 fields in schemas.

```
<fieldType name="text_field" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" />
<field name="title" type="text_field" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="content" type="text_field" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

`title` and `content` field returns 2 language values. 1. Turkish, 2. English

```
title:[
    "Orta Doğu Teknik Üniversitesi",
    "Middle East Technical University"
]

content:[
    "Örnek içerik",
    "Example content"
]
```

**Problem**

When I index it, I want `title` and `content` fields to be split into `title_tr`, `title_en` and `content_tr`, `content_en`.

I know I will use [LanguageDetection](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection) to detect and update the language. But I do not know how to make my request.

I use Solr 4.9.0 version.

---

```
<field name="title_en" type="text_field" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="content_en" type="text_field" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="title_tr" type="text_field" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="content_tr" type="text_field" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<copyField source="title" dest="title_tr"/>
<copyField source="content" dest="content_tr"/>
<copyField source="title" dest="title_en"/>
<copyField source="content" dest="content_en"/>
```

I want the result:

```
title_tr:[
    "Orta Doğu Teknik Üniversitesi"
]

title_en:[
    "Middle East Technical University"
]

content_tr:[
    "Örnek içerik"
]

content_en:[
    "Example content"
]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you using DataImportHandler?

Comment: @Oyeme, Nope, i using solr4j.

Comment: @Oyeme, and I have the final state before indexing data:
`title:[
    "Orta Doğu Teknik Üniversitesi",
    "Middle East Technical University"
]

content:[
    "Örnek içerik",
    "Example content"
]`

Comment: why dont you use update chain processor for this ?

Comment: I did not try the solution. Because I had to deal with another project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve it Solr side, I would recommend to develop you own UpdateRequestProcessor[1] .

You can implement there your logic :

1) scan each value from the multi field

2) identify the language ( you can take a look to the approach from this UpdateRequestprocessor[2]

3) create a field text_ with the value to index

[1] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/update-request-processors.html

[2] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0//solr-langid/org/apache/solr/update/processor/LangDetectLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory.html